# Is it possible to de-serialise pagingState in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

My data is stored among multiple partitions. I was to send this data to the client but I want to paginate the response. So say my 1st partition has 100 rows and 2nd partition has 100 rows. I want to send 10 rows per page along with `PagingState`. The client would send `PagingState` back to server and I'll use it to fetch next 10 records running the same query. Once I have exhausted 100 rows of 1st partition, I'll have to change the query. Is it possible to find which query was executed from `PagingState` so that I could read the `PagingState`, find for which partition it was for and using this information, I can determine what should be next partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible, but not straight forward or safe. The content changes between (protocol and cassandra) versions. Its also not very trivial to parse, as latest uses var ints to mark size of both partition key and row marker. On older versions it requires to send a cell level marker as well which it still sends for backwards compatibility in some scenarios so should really handle both. And with new versions of C* you will need to check to see if it changes.

You can always do paging on client side which will give you control over it and knowledge of the state that wont change on versions.